# Getting EscapeHelper doesnt exist after magento upgrade to 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

Getting below error after upgrade to 2.2.6:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper does not exist

I have checked vendor/magento/framework folder and didn't found EscapeHelper file while same exist in previous versions like 2.1.7

Any idea on how we can fix the above exception? I have checked even magento core files are using EscapeHelper class in vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\login.phtml e.g. $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password'))

Some of custom modules in my website are also using it same way.

Answer (score 6):

When you update magento 2.1 to 2.3 you will get this issue if your custom theme copied file from 2.1 theme.
You need to find all files whish use class
$this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->
then replace with 
$block->

It will resolve this issue.

Comment: running `grep -rl "this->helper(\\\Magento\\\Framework\\\EscapeHelper::class)" app/design/* | xargs sed -i 's/this->helper(\\Magento\\Framework\\EscapeHelper::class)/block/g'` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

With Magento 2.2 the methods from `EscapeHelper` have been moved to `Magento\Framework\Escaper`.

Comment: Any idea on how we can fix the above exception? I have checked even magento core files are using EscapeHelper class in vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\login.phtml e.g. $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password'))

Comment: @tony111ization can you please search your extensions code for `EscapeHelper`? If you've found anything please add it to your question.